# Would it increase the server load if embed YouTube live streaming videos?

Tags: video, youtube, streaming, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

If we embed YouTube live feed directly on our website, would it increase our server load and therefore increase the chance to have a site crash? I want to say no because the video is actually pulling from YouTube server? Whereas the website is only providing a frame-like window in the browser? It will be nice if someone could confirm this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sometimes yes

**NO**

There is no extra server load as both the player and the video content are retrieved on the client directly from the YouTube servers.

Answer (score -1):

sometimes yes, mostly not. if it would crash it would be a miscommunicating between youtube and the site. sometimes it crashes on like a mobile device or something. but that is pure the device. the site shouldn't crash.